# Error: socket hang up using https

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

My application crashes after a while with this error:

> { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 31.13.92.51:443
>       at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
>       at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
>       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)   code: 'ETIMEDOUT',   errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',   syscall: 'connect',
>   address: '31.13.92.51',   port: 443 }
>
> { Error: socket hang up
>       at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:253:15)
>       at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (_http_client.js:285:23)
>       at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at _handle.close (net.js:497:12)
>       at TCP.done [as _onclose] (_tls_wrap.js:332:7) code: 'ECONNRESET' }

I don't see anything wrong in my code, how can i handle this error?

```
try {
    https.get('https://www.instagram.com/'+username+'/?__a=1', function(resp){
        var body = '';
        resp.setEncoding('utf8');
        resp.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
        resp.on('end', function () {
            try {
                var json = JSON.parse(body);
            } catch (error) {
                callback('Unable to fetch user info from Instagram.', null);
                return;
            }
            callback(null, json.user);
        });
    });
}catch (error){
    callback("Connection to Instagram failed.", null);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried the same with `https` module, I've had the same problem, so I decided to go with another module which is `request` module, it seemed to work fine. I don't know why but `https` can't get resp from `instagram.com` , as I've tried already. This is what you can try as it worked for me. Install `request` module

```
    var request = require("request");
    var ext = '/?__a=1';
    var username = //username here;


    request
      .get('https://www.instagram.com/'+ username + ext)
      .on('response', function(response) {
        console.log(response.statusCode) // 200 is what I get from request
        console.log(response.headers['content-type'])
      })
```